# using join in mysql is not working with where caluse

Tags: php, mysql, html

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT Genomics_data_ncbi.Gene_name, Genomics_data_ncbi.Gene_id, 
Drug_targets_new.Genetic_and_biochemical_evidence
FROM Genomics_data_ncbi
JOIN Drug_targets_new ON Drug_targets_new.Gene_name = 
Genomics_data_ncbi.Gene_name WHERE Genomics_data_ncbi.Gene_name LIKE CONCAT ( 
'%', AUO97_RS18755, '%' )
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Comment: It is showing error - #1054 - Unknown column 'AUO97_RS18755' in 'where clause'

Comment: Do you mean something like `Genomics_data_ncbi.Gene_name LIKE  '%AUO97_RS18755%' ` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Probably missing quotes:

```
LIKE CONCAT ( '%', 'AUO97_RS18755', '%' )
```

or maybe

```
LIKE CONCAT ( '%AUO97_RS18755%' )
```

Comment: Still not working SELECT Genomics_data_ncbi.Gene_name, Genomics_data_ncbi.Gene_id, Drug_targets_new.Genetic_and_biochemical_evidence
FROM Genomics_data_ncbi
JOIN Drug_targets_new ON Drug_targets_new.Gene_name = Genomics_data_ncbi.Gene_name WHERE WHERE Genomics_data_ncbi.Gene_name LIKE CONCAT ( '%AUO97_RS18755%' )

Comment: I ma using this command but neither it displays any error nor gives output why?           SELECT Genomics_data_ncbi.Gene_name, Genomics_data_ncbi.Gene_id, Drug_targets_new.Genetic_and_biochemical_evidence
FROM Genomics_data_ncbi
JOIN Drug_targets_new ON Genomics_data_ncbi.Gene_name = Drug_targets_new.Gene_name WHERE Genomics_data_ncbi.Gene_name = 'AUO97_RS18755'